# Multiple APK: Version 1 is not served to any device configuration

Tags: android

After hours of searching the problem I have found that one dependency is causing the problem and because of this I have 0 supported devices when trying to publish my apk .
The dependency is `com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.0.0` from

https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android

any suggestions on how i can solve this issue ?

Thank You

Comment: what is your minSdkVersion?

Comment: well. It seems you found the issue yourself: https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android/issues/14

Comment: yes this is the problem,I am waiting for it to be fixed.

Comment: if you don't want to wait, check my answer below.

Comment: i will try it,Thank you @Budius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can play around with the manifest merger to remove the libraries `maxSdkVersion`

Official docs:
 http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-tools:overrideLibrary-marker

add the following line **inside** your `uses-sdk` node on the manifest:

```
tools:overrideLibrary="com.ramotion.foldingcell"
```

**Alternatively:**

you can use the gradle hack [described here](https://gist.github.com/goldierox/9533466) to replace `maxSdkVersion` to `minSdkVersion`

Comment: It works ,I have used the manifest merger,you have mentioned grade hack ,where can i read about it?

Comment: @Maximtoyberman sorry, I forgot to add the link. I added now.